# Re-applying to a Ph.D. program after acceptance?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science

What would happen if I were accepted into a Ph.D. program but declined it later in order to work in industry. Would this have any beneficial or negative impact on a future application to this same university and Ph.D. program?

My field is computer science.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to make generalizations due to the varying selectivity of programs. That said, there are a finite number of first-round offers any graduate program can make. In our department, if we ‘spent’ one on a candidate who then decided not to take it, we would probably hesitate to accept them the next time.

That said, a few years later the people reviewing applications may have changed, and university IT systems vary, so in a large graduate program they may not even know that you had applied in the past.

Comment: Are you able to "defer" the acceptance of the PhD role?

Comment: @user760900 Deferrals are relatively rare in science PhDs, AFAIK, and usually are restricted to extreme need (illness, family issues). This may change in COVID, but per the OP's Q, deferring to work in industry is generally not something that happens. Deferrals are usually only a year anyway. Although, I don't work in a field that has a large industry presence, so maybe it's different.

Comment: Agreed - deferrals are relatively rare in my experience. It basically requires that we find somebody else for this year, and reduce our spots for next year. As @AzorAhai--hehim notes, of course, if there's documented need we'd been generous.

Comment: I suppose this answer is culture-dependent. In my country (France) PhD selection is like a job interview: the advisor defines the (general path of the) research program first, gets a budget for it, and hires whoever they can find for that position. With that framework, there is no issue of losing a spot before the contract is signed; if my top-choice candidate refuses a PhD offer to do something else, I will hire the next in line, and I would have no issue with them reapplying to a new position a year later.

Comment: Interesting context, @UJM - thanks!